# Searching array by unique pair constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres database table containing a unique constraint on `field1` and `field2`.
I have an array of values of field1 and a fixed value for field2 that I wish to use for searching.

How can I 'pair' the array of field1 values to the fixed field2 value and search which 'pairs' match the unique constraint?

So if I have records

```
ID: 1
field1: 1
field2: 2

ID: 2
field1: 2
field2: 2

ID: 3
field1: 3
field2: 2
```

And the array of field1 values

```
1,3,5
```

and fixed value `2` for field2, then my search should return records 1 and 3, since the unique constraints of field1,field2 are 1,2 and 3,2

EDIT: I can manually 'pair' the values in the array if that makes the query easier to create

Comment: Should the array of field1 values be [1,2,3] not [1,3,5]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "pairing", you can just use normal `WHERE` filters.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.field1 = ANY(ARRAY[1, 3, 5])
  AND t.field2 = 2;
```

Or using a normal `IN` clause

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.field1 IN (1, 3, 5)
  AND t.field2 = 2;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/gJBPFJiJ)

Comment: I massively overthought the problem, the combination of IN and AND is exactly what I need, thank you

Comment: `IN ANY` is a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry fixed now